# Numbering rows from 1 to N based on a column value

Tags: sql, presto

Sample:

```
id  value  
1   a  
1   b  
1   c  
1   d  
1   a  
1   b  
1   d  
1   a
```

Expected outcome:

```
id  value   outcome  
1   a   1  
1   b   1  
1   c   1  
1   d   1  
1   a   2  
1   b   2  
1   d   2  
1   a   3
```

So the basic idea is that I need to number the rows I have based on the value column - whenever it reaches "d", the count starts over. Not sure which kind of window function I'd use do to that, so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`row_number` window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) with partition by `value` or by `id` and `value` (based on desired output):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, value) as(
    values (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b'),
        (1, 'c'),
        (1, 'd'),
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b'),
        (1, 'd'),
        (1, 'a')
)

-- query
select *,
    row_number() over (partition by id, value) -- or (partition by value)
from dataset;
```

Note that if there is no column which will allow "natural" ordering for the `over` clause (i.e. `over (partition by id, value order by some_column_like_timestamp)`) then the actual order is not guaranteed between queries (you will be able to observe it if there are other columns present which has different values in the same partition).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`row_number`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) to give them a unique number, then order by row_number and value.

```
select
  *,
  row_number() over ( partition by (val) ) as rn
from stuff
order by rn, val;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ug6Vu_Dn)